# Getting 400 Bad Request Request from WCF services when moving into application request routing web farm

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, arr

We just moved our B2B shop into a web farm environment using Application Request Routing. We are now in the testphase. Everything seems to work just fine except all the WCF POST calls. Every single one of them keeps giving 400 bad request.

If I access each server in the farm I get the same 400 bad request error. We have not tampered with the config files they are exactly the same as when the site ran on one single server.

Does anybody know what I can check, or where to begin? The old site is still up and running fine so I can't figure out why the WCF calls gives 400 bad request when we set up the site in the web farm.

//Cheers